# Upload and display image to Cloudant with PHP in BlueMix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a small php app running in BlueMix. I want provide upload possibility and to store the image in Cloudant since it is not possible to store directly in BlueMix. Then I want to display the uploaded image.

Is there some sample code for uploading and retrieving images to and from Cloudant in Bluemix?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Images are just binary data, so the more general form of this question is, is there samples for uploading and storing binary data in CouchDB (since Cloudant is a hosted CouchDB)?  Look at "Attachments" on the CouchDB reference or the Cloudant reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are two boilerplates on Bluemix that show you how to store and retrieve images as attachments on Cloudant. They are written in [Node.js](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/nodejs-cloudant-db-web-starter/) and [Java](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/java-cloudant-web-starter/), but it should still help you.

Cloudant is based on the Apache-backed CouchDB project and the open source BigCouch project.

This [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-couchdb/) has sample code to interact with couchdb using php

You will get a lot more results if you google for "php couchdb attachments"

Comment: Integrating Ram's answer, here you can find a guide to use CouchDB with PHP
http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/couchdb-for-php-developers-crud/